# JSExportAs not changing method name in javascript

Tags: javascript, ios, objective-c

I can't figure out how to use JSExportAs.  In the javascript debugger it looks like it still is using openMenuItemType.

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <JavaScriptCore/JavaScriptCore.h>

@protocol WebViewJavascriptExports<JSExport>

+ (void) log:(NSString *) message;
+ (void) refreshRoles;
JSExportAs(openMenu,
    + (void) openMenuItem:(id)name type:(id)type
);

@end

@interface WebViewJavascriptInterface : NSObject<WebViewJavascriptExports>

@end
```

Comment: JSExportAs does simply establish a hint for the JSVM how to alias the nam. Internally your method will still be called with it's original name. Also maybe this helps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23276548/cant-jsexport-an-objective-c-method-with-more-than-one-parameter